# JavaScript String split with multiple delimiters while keeping the delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split a string in JavaScript using multiple delimiters while still keeping the delimiters.
I tried it with this RegEx but I get matches I'm not interested in.

`"id:123 name:test pumpe desc:pumpe p123".split(/(?=(id:))|(?=(name:))|(?=(desc:))/gi)`

The Output I get:

`["id:123 ", undefined, "name:", undefined, "name:test pumpe ", undefined, undefined, "desc:", "desc:pumpe p123"]`

The Output I want:

`["id:123", "name:test pumpe", "desc:pumpe p123"]`

I tried plaing a bit with the regex but couldn't get my desired output.

Comment: `.split(/\s+(?=(?:id|name|desc):)/i)`?

Answer (score 1):

The delimiters you actually want to split by are spaces, specifically, spaces that are followed by `name:`, `id:` or `desc:`.

Following this logic, this regex can be constructed:

```
/ (?=name:|id:|desc)/i
```

(Note the initial space)

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/0RxEU9/1

```js
console.log("id:123 name:test pumpe desc:pumpe p123".split(/ (?=name:|id:|desc)/i))
```

Comment: When used in `.split`, the `g` modifier is not required, `split()` splits at all occurrences in the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for a space and following by not space and a colon.

```js
console.log("id:123 name:test pumpe desc:pumpe p123".split(/\s(?=\S+?:)/));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for anything that follows the pattern `[name:]|[desc:]|[id:]` so simplify your regex:

```js
console.log("id:123 name:test pumpe desc:pumpe p123".split(/ (?=name:|id:|desc:)/i));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the key names are unknown you could do `split` at every `\s` which is followed by `\w+:`

([Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EvNMQp/1))

```js
const splits = "id:123 name:test pumpe desc:pumpe p123".split(/\s+(?=\w+:)/)
console.log(splits)
```